# zoomable scrollview ANDROID

Tags: android, scrollview

Hey i have made a horizontal scrollview inside a vertical scrollview so I can scroll on both, x & y axis. Inside the scrollview is a huge table (12x8). Now I want to make all that zoomable (so the table/the table's contents become bigger/smaller)

Just in case someone needs it: here the view hierarchy

```
relative layout
 scrollview
  horizontalScrollView
   LinearLayout
    TableLayout
     (table rows)
    /TableLayout
   /LinearLayout
  /horizontalScrollView
 /scrollview
/relative layout
```

I didn't find any good solutions, I hope you can help me